# How to reconstruct the seed of Math.random()?

Tags: javascript, random, cryptography

I know that using Math.random() for cryptography purposes is insecure. I need an example code of reconstructing Math.random() function used in javascript to generate random numbers. for example if I have a random number generated by Math.random(), how can I figure out what the seed was?

Comment: guess a random seed until it works

Comment: A single number does not imply a particular seed value.

Comment: Do you have any way to know how many times the PRNG was called?

Comment: You can't specify a seed for `Math.random()`, it's an internal detail.

Comment: [That said: _"The random number generator is seeded from the current time, as in Java."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: *"Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately uniform distribution over that range, **using an implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy**."* http://es5.github.com/#x15.8.2.14 Meaning, which JavaScript engine do you want to simulate?

Comment: @MattBall [Unless you use Opera](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webcrypto/2013Jan/0063.html)

Comment: @FelixKling Say I wanna simulate mozilla.

Comment: `Math.random` isn't *guaranteed* to be secure, but it can be secure. A least in Opera it is. So you have no chance to recover the seed when you use Opera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the source. In this case, it's in [mozilla/js/src/jsmath.cpp](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/src/jsmath.cpp#525):

```
static const uint64_t RNG_MULTIPLIER = 0x5DEECE66DLL;
static const uint64_t RNG_ADDEND = 0xBLL;
static const uint64_t RNG_MASK = (1LL << 48) - 1;
static const double RNG_DSCALE = double(1LL << 53);

/*
 * Math.random() support, lifted from java.util.Random.java.
 */

...

extern uint64_t random_next(uint64_t *rngState, int bits)
{
    uint64_t nextstate = *rngState * RNG_MULTIPLIER;
    nextstate += RNG_ADDEND;
    nextstate &= RNG_MASK;
    *rngState = nextstate;
    return nextstate >> (48 - bits);
}

static inline double random_nextDouble(JSContext *cx)
{
    uint64_t *rng = &cx->compartment->rngState;
    return double((random_next(rng, 26) << 27) + random_next(rng, 27)) / RNG_DSCALE;
}
```

So,

1. Call `Math.random()`
2. Multiply by 2<sup>53</sup> to get an integer `n` (you'll want to explicitly use uint64_t)
3. Split it into the (upper bits of the) RNG outputs: the top 26 bits `n>>27` and the bottom 27 bits `n&((1<<27)-1)`.
4. The 27-bit can be from *either* the first or second RNG output (like C, I don't think C++ places any guarantee on the order of evaluation here). So...

   - Iterate over the 2<sup>21</sup> possible lower bits.
   - See if you can get there by running the RNG forwards *or* backwards.
   - If so, output that number as a candidate.

Due to the nature of the RNG, having multiple candidates may be a possibility.

Running the RNG backwards is an exercise to the reader (you simply need to calculate the multiplicative inverse of 0x5DEECE66D modulo 2<sup>48</sup>). Alternatively, you can take the 26-bit number and guess all 2<sup>22</sup> possible inputs.

Comment: Thanks, apparently, it works the same as nextDouble() in Java.